# How can I symlink a subdirectory of /usr/share/ca-certificates?

Tags: ssl

I have some self-signed certificates located in `/mnt/raid/ssl` that I would like to add to my `/usr/share/ca-certificates`.  So far I've tried the following:

1. `sudo ln -s /mnt/raid/ssl /usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`
2. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates  # certificates under ./extra don't appear`
3. `sudo update-ca-certificates`

The output to step `3` is as follows:

```
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that subdirectories containing certificates will not be processed. Maybe try to symlink the certificates separate in the top level directory.

Comment: @remyseroos, this is surprising since there are two directories in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra`:  `mozilla` and `spi-inc.org`.  I've also seen several tutorials that recommend creating an `extra` directory for self-signed certs.

Comment: Try copying the directory in directly?  It may be a case that the symlinks aren't followed

Comment: @ThomasW., the whole point is to store the directory on the RAID array, so I'd rather avoid that solution if at all possible.

Comment: @blz I meant temporarily, to see if that is the case, not as a long term solution

Comment: @ThomasW. Ah, okay, sorry!  Yes, copying the directory to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` works just fine.

Comment: Hmm, this looks related; https://serverfault.com/questions/585038/why-do-i-need-to-create-symbolic-links-for-certificates

Answer (score 1):

Try placing them in (a subdirectory of) `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` instead of `/usr/share/ca-certificates`. That location is also mentioned in `/usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian` (on Debian 8 Jessie).